# Asp.net & c# Error: The name "mygv" does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to bind data to the grid named 'mygv' but I get the error **"The name "mygv" does not exist in the current context"**. There are similar questions like this here but the solutions provided did not work for me.This is what I have done.

**new.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace DistrictEfts
{
    public  partial class _new : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


            public  void Generate_Efts(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
                StreamReader sr=null;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                DataRow dr;
                string column1 = "";
                string column2="";
                string column3="";
                string column4="";
                string column5="";
                string column6="";
                string column7="";
                string column8="";
                string column9="";

                try
                {
                    sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~\\1623107554X.PAY"));
                    string eachline = "";
                    string[] colval = null;
                    int i = 0;
                    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        //Read line by line
                        eachline = sr.ReadLine();
                        //Formatting the file contents
                        string s = Regex.Replace(eachline , @"[^\w'""&:;-()-]+", " ,");
                        colval = eachline.Split(',');


                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            column1 = colval[0];
                            column2 = colval[1];
                            column3 = colval[2];
                            column4 = colval[3];
                            column5 = colval[4];
                            column6 = colval[5];
                            column7 = colval[6];
                            column8 = colval[7];
                            column9 = colval[8];
                            dt.Columns.Add(column1);
                            dt.Columns.Add(column2);
                            dt.Columns.Add(column3);
                            dt.Columns.Add(column4);
                            dt.Columns.Add(column5);
                            dt.Columns.Add(column6);
                            dt.Columns.Add(column7);
                            dt.Columns.Add(column8);
                            dt.Columns.Add(column9);
                            i = i + 1;
                        }
                        //Add values in the datatable columns
                        else
                        {
                            dr = dt.NewRow();
                           dr[ column1] = colval[0];
                            dr[column2] = colval[1];
                            dr[column3] = colval[2];
                            dr[column4] = colval[3];
                            dr[column5] = colval[4];
                            dr[column6] = colval[5];
                            dr[column7] = colval[6];
                            dr[column8] = colval[7];
                            dr[column9] = colval[8];
                            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                        }
                    }
                    sr.Close();
                    mygv.DataSource = dt;
                    mygv.DataBind();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
                finally
                {

                }
            }
}
}
```

**new.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="new.aspx.cs" Inherits=" _new" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="800" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td height="60">
                    <p> District efts</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="30" align="center">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="50" align="center">
                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Generate Efts" 
                        onclick="Generate_Efts" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <asp:GridView ID="mygv" runat="server" Width="400">
                    </asp:GridView>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Will be grateful for any help.
Thanks.

Comment: may be your designer.cs is corrupted or not generated try to regenerate designer for your webform.

Comment: It is generated. @HassaanKhan .

Answer (score 3):

A couple of issues. To start with, the attribute CodeBehind is not used in asp.net 2.0. You should use CodeFile instead.

Next, you cannot put your Page class in a namespace - and if you could, it would have to be the same as referred to in your Inherits attribute: TaskList vs TaskGridList.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this my adding the namespace of my page class to my Inherits attribute since my page class was in a namespace.

Was

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="new.aspx.cs" Inherits="_new" %>
```

And now changed to

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="new.aspx.cs" Inherits=" DistrictEfts._new" %>
```

This worked for me.